# HR tag not showing up a right place

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add `hr` tag after every 4 div in the following code, for some reason it doesn't show at correctly on fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/UHqWF/14/

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/UHqWF/16/

```
<hr>
<div class="imageitem"><div>Image Item</div></div>
<div class="imageitem"><div>Image Item</div></div>
<div class="imageitem"><div>Image Item</div></div>
<div class="imageitem"><div>Image Item</div></div>
   <hr>
<div class="imageitem"><div>Image Item</div></div>
<div class="imageitem"><div>Image Item</div></div>
<div class="imageitem"><div>Image Item</div></div>
<div class="imageitem"><div>Image Item</div></div>
   <hr>
<div class="imageitem"><div>Image Item</div></div>
<div class="imageitem"><div>Image Item</div></div>
<div class="imageitem"><div>Image Item</div></div>
<div class="imageitem"><div>Image Item</div></div>
```

**Solution**: My above approach is tedious & will complicate design with differnt screen sizes.

I think it is better to add `border-top:1px solid red;` to `imageitem` div

```
.imageitem {
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
             box-sizing:border-box;
        float:left;
        padding:10px;
        width:100%;
        border-top:1px solid red;
         border-bottom:0px solid red;
    }
```

Comment: if you give it a `width:100%` ?

Comment: I did that on desktop, but then it overlapse the div by pixels.

Comment: You should edit a question to *clarify the question*, not to post an answer or tell about some other approach.

Answer (score 6):

It's because you have floated your elements. Add `hr {clear: both;}` css rule to fix it.

Comment: THis show the hr but overlaps the divs by certain margin. i am facing same issue on my desktop. How can i give equal margin

Comment: If you add `margin:30px;` it will remain at same position after first 4 dive. It overlaps extra margins